# Why is it that I have to press on my button twice to make the in app purchase initiate in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I don't get why that is happening. When I tap on the button once to intiate the payment process nothing happens. When I tap it twice then the in app purchase initiates and I could start the payment process. Why does this happen. Here is some of the code: BTW I have more code if you want to see it:

In my GameScene I have this function:

```
    func callthis() {

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "unlockLevelTwo")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")

    }
}
```

Im calling this function in my GameViewController like this:

```
      override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      gameScene.callthis()

      }
```

Back in my GameScene I have the button with this code inside it:

```
     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if node.name == "unlockleveltwobuttonNow" {

        callthis()

        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "unlockLevelTwo") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break;


            }
        }
        runAction(menuAudioPlayer)


    }
```

Comment: It may be better to use a traditional for loop to iterate through all of the touches in touchesBegan. Use `for touch: AnyObject in touches {...}` instead of declaring the touch separately and then using an if statement. I think the problem may be with the declaration of the touch variable. Using the for loop runs this code for every touch so you won't need to tap twice.

Comment: @TheCodeComposer I did it a bit differently right now. I added a confirmation button and in there I put the buyProduvt() function and it works. What do you think?

Comment: If it works, then feel free to use it but most people use the for loop I mentioned earlier so it is good practice to use them. If someone else reads your code they may expect to see a for loop. If this works for you, then go for it, especially if you'll be the only one seeing the code. Happy coding.